# Effect of work experience in gaining PHD acceptance

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a senior in water resources engineering. I graduated in master degree in 2008. After that I have worked in cosulting companies to now in my expertise. Recently, I am intrested in studying in water resource,PHD. Is having work experience positive point in gaining acceptace for PHD or not?

Comment: What's a "senior"?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your experience. While the academical and research-based works through your consulting profession would be interesting, the typical works are not positive in the academical settings.

If you can explain your earlier experiences through research and development elements and illustrate your ambition to solve the profession challenges as the main cause for entering the PhD course, then it would be a strong positive impact on the acceptance in the interview of the PhD.